# Change language for authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic to English?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I work in my French Rails project but I want to set English language for `authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic` used with Rail-admin. It is currently displayed in French. How can I set the language to English ?

I tried setting locale with `gem 'rails-i18n'`. But it had no effect.

## app/config/initializers/rails-admin.rb

```
  config.authenticate_with do
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic('Login required') do |username, password|
      admin = Admin.where(name:username).first
      admin.authenticate(password) if admin
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prompt/dialog to login is built within the browser and cannot be changed by the server(rails).

Just try changing the locale of the machine where you open your rails app and you will see prompt as per the language set.

Comment: Thanks ;) It was very simple in fact